# How does IE calculate the CSS element width:100%?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, width

Trying to get information on this so I can answer my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367956/div-width-problem-in-ie).

Comment: Is your page live? If so, please send a link.

Comment: It is live, but intranet.  I update via FTP.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes the width of the parent element and sets the width of the current element to 100% of it.

What you may have run into, however, is the [IE box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) (which is still present in 'Quirks Mode').

Specifically, when in quirks mode, IE includes padding within the area defined by 'width', while the W3C box model does not - both padding and margin are added onto the width.

Comment: Ok, so if the parent element is the body tag, shouldn't a div tag with 100% width contained in the body tag be 100% of the page?  Also, I am using IE8 and XHTML strict, so I unless my document has errors I do not see, I don't think the box model bug is the problem.

Comment: After trying many different combination I found one that worked.  Using compatibility mode in IE8 was the final thing that made it work, but I must have changed something else in the process because I tried compatibility mode many times in the past 24 hours and it didn't work.  Any way, at least I know what the problem is, now I just need to find out how to force a page to load in compatibility mode.  One more thing, @Amber, are you considering `Quirks Mode` and `Compatibility Mode` the same thing???

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [THIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) page for more detailed information.